# How do I hash something x times with sha256 and output them into a file or show them on screen?

Tags: javascript, php, hash, echo

for example i want to hash password 10 times it would look like this

1. 6b3a55e0261b0304143f805a24924d0c1c44524821305f31d9277843b8a10f4e

2. 3e49d361ee0f48388c7383d80703c80a773555f9e0bd563f559310abb14680a0

3. c3e1ff07b9a1b4bcf26860c2e99cb5566720052e71ac6fb531e3de36e412e36a

4. 730f32f9074394d5afd5f401d0eaa67a7566897bdb450ab4d5d4fa3c3a24b948

etc..

Comment: 1. You have both Javascript and PHP tags.  Which of the two do you want?

2. This seems trivially simple.  Have you done any programming before, or what is the reason for asking such a trivially simple question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hash_pass($pass, $times = 10){
    for($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++){
         $pass = hash('sha256', $pass);
         echo $pass;
    }
}
```

But why would you want to hash password so many times. If you are concerned about security I suggest you read something on security. this [post](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) might help you.

Comment: `But why would you want to hash password so many times`  Hashing the password many times in a loop is a legitimate and well-respected way of hashing passwords in an application, though normally you would do this with bcrypt (PHP's crypt() function) or PBKDF2 (PHP's pbkdf2() function) which takes care of the hashing and the loop for you, and ensures portability and security.

Comment: Im trying to figure out the start of a chain of hashed hashes for example here is the list of hashes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 hashing 11 gives you 10, 10 gives you 9, 9 gives you 8 etc but i want 12 without 13 i cannot find 12. but if i hash something 20 times and get 1-20 i can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

1: write a hash function

```
function hashCode(s){
  return s.split("").reduce(function(a,b){a=((a<<5)-a)+b.charCodeAt(0);return a&a},0);              
}
```

2: run it many times:

```
var times = 10, i = 0, password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", outputStr = "";
while(i<=times){
  outputStr +=hashCode(password) + "\n";
  i++;
}
//out put the string
console.log(outputStr);
```

Comment: Obviously you'd need to replace the hash function as that wouldn't give a SHA256 hash.